# "market://details?id=" says item not found

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

I am trying to add rating feature in my app https://github.com/codechimp-org/AppRater but, the every time I click on the `rate now` it says `The item you requested could not be found`.
How do I get out of this trouble. I am using

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                                .parse("market://details?id=com.xxx.xxx")));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Rate This App"-link in Google Play store app on the phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816757/rate-this-app-link-in-google-play-store-app-on-the-phone)

Comment: Is app available for that specific device for which your testing? As it seems your testing for Google Market. Right?

Comment: @FahadIshaque: Yes it is. I testing it on Sony Xperia x8(android 2.1)

Comment: Did you hardcode the string or are you generating it from like context.getPackageName()?

Answer (score 0):

Your url does not seem right.

It should be `"market://details?id="+ context.getPackageName().toString()`

It seems you really tried to copy/paste some sample without really understanding what you were writting...

Comment: Sorry Orabîg. my url is correct <market://details?id=com.xxx.xxx>, its just that I did commit a mistake while doing copy paste in my question.

Comment: ok, I understand. Then can you confirm that the corresponding https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xxxx URL does work on the web ?

Comment: Yes it does work on the web but on the phone it launches the `googleplay` but says item not found.