# Directly open up the Play store rating screen from our app in android

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to directly open up the rating screen dialog of play store app of a particular appllication?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Rate This App"-link in Google Play store app on the phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816757/rate-this-app-link-in-google-play-store-app-on-the-phone)

Answer (score 3):

Try this..

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + context.getPackageName());
Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
try {
  startActivity(goToMarket);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
  Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't launch the market", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Or

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);                     
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=Your Main Package Name"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This would open the page of our app in play store. Then the user have to open the rating screen. I need the rating screen to be poped up . Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @NavyaRamesan I don't think this is possible, you can't directly interact with the market and post a rating of your app. You can only open the rating-page of the market and let the user rate himself.

Comment: @NavyaRamesan The rating is done through market app so that ratings can be trusted. If apps were allowed to handle the rating themselves, then developer could increase his app's rating any time. So there is no way you can handle the rating yourself. You can prompt user to your app page on google play and ask him to rate your app for more support.

Comment: Refer the links also https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/188189?hl=en and http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html#marketintent

Comment: Alright. But I don't need the rating to be done. Need to popup the rating dialog alone. Wondering if android provides some way to popup the rating screen itself.

Comment: Is this still the case? I am pretty sure I have seen apps directing directly to the store and opening the rating screen. @NavyaRamesan have you found a solution for this in the meantime?

Comment: the "rating page" not the app page.

Comment: you can find a more detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10816846/997940