# How to give my app's reference encoding a "Rate my app" page in my app before publishing my app on play store

Tags: java, android, ios, google-play

I am developing a kids-app and I have to add a rate-us page in my app, but I am not aware how I can do it before publishing my app,here is the code for rating my app but what URL I will give?

```
      Uri uri =Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/detailsid=com.internetdesignzone.nurseryrhymes&hl=en");

      Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
      gotoMark.goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
            startActivity(goToMarket);
```

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10816846/1529129) will help you

Comment: Just i want to find a criteria

Comment: `Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + context.getPackageName());` this is what you need

Comment: @RahulTiwari by putting this code,user will be able to rate us my app when i will upload my app on any play store. am i right? i just wanted to know that if my app is not yet live in play store , how will place the link of app in rate us and share us ?

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use :

`Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + context.getPackageName());`

Applications are identified by their package name, on play store as well URL of application consist of package name as a parameter.

If you Will construct your uri this way, said parameter will be filled by your apps package name and a proper URL will be constructed for your app.

However this URL will only work once your app is uploaded and published successfully on play store. Till then you will get 404 page not found.