# Is it possible to automatically open rating dialog of play store app after launching play store app from my app?

Tags: android, google-play-services, rating

I know how to open my app in play store but i want to open rating dialog of play store for my app like below image.[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Rate This App"-link in Google Play store app on the phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816757/rate-this-app-link-in-google-play-store-app-on-the-phone)

Comment: but answer is not available.

Comment: Google Play Store app doesn't allow direct navigation to Ratings dialog.

Comment: I think I have seen this in Google Keep. They opened the same dialog in the app itself. There must be some way!

Answer (score 0):

Rating can only be done using the play store app so that rating can be trusted. The reason being if rating would be allowed from other apps developers could potentially exploit it by rating themselves as 5 star without the user even knowing. You could try the below code to launch play store with your app loaded so the user can rate it there.

```
private void launchMarket() {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName());
    Intent myAppLinkToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    try {
        startActivity(myAppLinkToMarket);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, " unable to find market app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to open  rating dialog of play store automatically with launch of play store app.

Comment: Thats not possible as far as i can tell the max you can do is launch the default market app and load your app page on it :P

Comment: Maybe with reflection ... ?