# How to link to GooglePlay to rate a game (Unity3d)?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play

I use Unity3d make a game.
I want to make a button in the game, and players can click on this button to link GooglePlay and rate my game.
What plugin I need and how to do this?
I  just found this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816757/rate-this-app-link-in-google-play-store-app-on-the-phone)

Comment: So whats wrong with the link you found?

Comment: @lan H. It can't help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After clicking on button call

```
Application.OpenURL ("market://details?id=" + Application.productName);
```

Comment: i think you should use Application.identifier

Comment: This did not worked for me. I used Application.identifier instead. It kept giving me error "To view this content, install and set up a web browsing app."

Answer (score 7):

As you can change your application name and Google allow different name in the app and in the play store; better use `Application.identifier` rather than `Application.productName`;

**You can not change your application identifier or Package name after uploading the first APK**

```
public void OnClickRateUs()
{
    Application.OpenURL("market://details?id=" + `Application.identifier`);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

After a couple of times that the user have used your application, you can popup a message asking the user to rate the app. And if the user tap on `Ok` on dialogue, you can redirect the him with the below link to playstore for rating.

Link with button pressed 
`"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + yourcurrentActivity.this.getPackageName()` 
this link will open google playstore and show your application there.

PS. you can use Sharedprefs to keep record of the times the user launch your application.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, now I know 2 ways to do this.I love you too.

Comment: glad to help you. Show your love by the green tick.. ;)