# How to Open PlayStore Page in Unity Android

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, openurl

I tried to make a code that open a Playstore Page (in playstore app), in a test build apk. Code:

> Application.OpenURL("market://details?id=xxx.xxxxx.xxxxx/");

Using this code (and setting my Playstore id), in my Build apk starts to open Play Store and Show a message like "To view this content install and setup a web browsing app"

I just wanna test to open a Play Store page on any APK Build. Can I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45583730/how-to-link-to-googleplay-to-rate-a-game-unity3d Make sure to use `Application.identifier` as noted in the comments of the answer.

Comment: Don't works, It's a "test" app. This app isn't on play store, I'm trying to open another Playstore App Page to test

Comment: Seems like you're trying to do something that is not supported.