# Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core errors when I tried to use Google Play In-App Reviews API

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, build.gradle, google-play-services

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63404029/7639296), I am trying to add this lib [Google Play In-App Reviews API](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review) in my app and use it like the following

```
 rateTheApp.setOnClickListener {
                val manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(requireContext())
                val request = manager.requestReviewFlow()
                request.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        // We got the ReviewInfo object
                        val reviewInfo = request.result
                        val flow = manager.launchReviewFlow(requireActivity(), reviewInfo)

                        flow.addOnSuccessListener {
                            Log.d(TAG, "flow.addOnSuccessListener: sucess")
                        }

                        flow.addOnCompleteListener { _ ->
                            // The flow has finished. The API does not indicate whether the user
                            // reviewed or not, or even whether the review dialog was shown. Thus, no
                            // matter the result, we continue our app flow.
                            Log.d(TAG, "addOnCompleteListener: ${task.result}")
                            
                        }
                    } else {
                        // There was some problem, continue regardless of the result.
                        val errorCode = when (val exception = request.exception) {
                            is ReviewException -> {
                                exception.errorCode
                            }
                            is RuntimeExecutionException -> {
                                exception.errorCode
                            }
                            else -> {
                                9999
                            }
                        }

                        Log.e(TAG, "errorCode: $errorCode", )

                    }
                }
            }
```

the error log

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetLocation found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackException found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackExtractionService found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackLocation found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackManager found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackManagerFactory found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackState found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackStateUpdateListener found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackStates found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.NativeAssetPackStateUpdateListener found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.a found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.aa found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.ab found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.ac found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.ad found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.ae found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.af found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.ag found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.ah found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.ai found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.aj found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.ak found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.al found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.am found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.an found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.ao found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.ap found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.aq found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.ar found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.as found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.at found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.au found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.av found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.aw found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.ax found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.ay found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.az found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.b found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.ba found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.bb found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.bc found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.bd found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.be found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.bf found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.bg found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.bh found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.bi found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.bj found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.bk found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.bl found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.bm found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.bn found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.bo found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.bp found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.bq found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.br found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.bs found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.bt found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.bu found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.bv found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.bw found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.bx found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.by found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.bz found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.c found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.ca found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.ktx.AssetPackManagerKtxKt found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-ktx-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery-ktx:2.0.0) and jetified-core-ktx-1.8.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.ktx.AssetPackManagerKtxKt$requestCellularDataConfirmation$1 found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-ktx-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery-ktx:2.0.0) and jetified-core-ktx-1.8.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.ktx.AssetPackManagerKtxKt$requestFetch$1 found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-ktx-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery-ktx:2.0.0) and jetified-core-ktx-1.8.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.ktx.AssetPackManagerKtxKt$requestPackStates$1 found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-ktx-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery-ktx:2.0.0) and jetified-core-ktx-1.8.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.ktx.AssetPackManagerKtxKt$requestProgressFlow$1 found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-ktx-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery-ktx:2.0.0) and jetified-core-ktx-1.8.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.ktx.AssetPackManagerKtxKt$requestProgressFlow$1$1 found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-ktx-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery-ktx:2.0.0) and jetified-core-ktx-1.8.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.ktx.AssetPackManagerKtxKt$requestProgressFlow$1$2 found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-ktx-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery-ktx:2.0.0) and jetified-core-ktx-1.8.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.ktx.AssetPackManagerKtxKt$requestProgressFlow$1$3 found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-ktx-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery-ktx:2.0.0) and jetified-core-ktx-1.8.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.ktx.AssetPackManagerKtxKt$requestProgressFlow$1$globalSessionListener$1 found in modules jetified-asset-delivery-ktx-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:asset-delivery-ktx:2.0.0) and jetified-core-ktx-1.8.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.ktx.ReviewManagerKtxKt found in modules jetified-core-ktx-1.8.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1) and jetified-review-ktx-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:review-ktx:2.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.ktx.ReviewManagerKtxKt$requestReview$1 found in modules jetified-core-ktx-1.8.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1) and jetified-review-ktx-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:review-ktx:2.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.listener.StateUpdatedListener found in modules jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0) and jetified-core-common-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewInfo found in modules jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0) and jetified-review-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:review:2.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewManager found in modules jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0) and jetified-review-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:review:2.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewManagerFactory found in modules jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0) and jetified-review-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:review:2.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.review.testing.FakeReviewManager found in modules jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0) and jetified-review-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:review:2.0.0)
```

**build.gradle (project)**

```
buildscript {
    ext {

        // Versions for all the dependencies we plan to use. It's particularly useful for kotlin and
        // navigation where the versions of the plugin needs to be the same as the version of the
        // library defined in the app Gradle file
        kotlin_version = "1.6.21"
        version_gradle = "7.3.0"
        version_core = "1.8.0"
//        version_lifecycle_extensions = "2.2.0"
        hilt_version = "2.42"
        nav_version = "2.5.2"
        room_version = "2.4.3"
        version_constraint_layout = "2.2.0-alpha03"
//        version_glide = "4.12.0"
        version_retrofit = "2.9.0"
        version_recyclerview = "1.2.1"
        version_material = "1.6.1"
        version_play_services = "21.2.0"
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$version_gradle"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.40.1"
        classpath "com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:2.0.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'

    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version "$version_gradle" apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version "$version_gradle" apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version "$kotlin_version" apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (app module)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'

}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.myapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    kapt {
        correctErrorTypes = true
    }
    namespace 'com.test.myapp'
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'

    implementation ('com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1')
            {
        exclude(group: 'androidx.recyclerview',  module: 'recyclerview')
        exclude(group: 'androidx.recyclerview',  module: 'recyclerview-selection')
    }
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
    // For control over item selection of both touch and mouse driven selection
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0"

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    //Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'

//    //Moshi
//    implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.13.0")
//    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0")
//    kapt "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.13.0"

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.14.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1'
    implementation 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.1.Final'
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0"

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
    }

    //Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.3"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.3"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.4.3"




    //Dagger - Hilt
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.42'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.42'


    //SDP & SSP
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'

    // Shimmer
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'

    //firebase & analytics
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

    //crashlytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'

    // DataStore
    implementation 'androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0'
    implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences-rxjava3:1.0.0")

    //admob
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.2.0'

    implementation("androidx.ads:ads-identifier:1.0.0-alpha04")

    // Used for the calls to addCallback() in the snippets on this page.
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:28.0-android")

    //for fcm
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.8'
    implementation 'android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
//
//    dependencies {
//        // debugImplementation because LeakCanary should only run in debug builds.
//        debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.9.1'
//    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.ump:user-messaging-platform:2.0.0'

    kapt("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.5.0")

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.1'

    implementation("com.google.android.play:asset-delivery-ktx:2.0.0")
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1'
    implementation("com.google.android.play:review-ktx:2.0.0")
    
}
```

Comment: Ever resolve this?

Comment: @devinm no, but I created an issue here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/252848051 please start it or click +1
It looks in app review library conflicts with some of the firebase dependencies like google ads

Answer (score 3):

This happens if you have a dependency on the now deprecated Google Play Core library and on the new libraries.

Google Play Core libraries have now been split into multiple libraries. There is [a documentation page](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore#playcore-migration) that describes the migration from the "old" Play Core library to multiple libraries based on your needs. The rest of the page describes all the available Google Play Core libraries.

In your case, you have to **REMOVE** the line

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1'
```

And only **KEEP** the lines (or for any other Google Play Core library listed in the documentation page linked above):

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:asset-delivery-ktx:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:review-ktx:2.0.1'
```

Note: I updated the version to that of the time of writing, you likely have to update them to the current version.