# Android App Rating - Populate store popup fields with in-app popup input

Tags: android, google-play, rate, user-friendly

I understand based on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270591/rate-google-play-application-directly-in-app) that I cant let user rate an Android application in-app via some Google Play Store API, but would it be possible to pre-populate the information the same way I just did when I implemented a client-only email feedback form [link](http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-email-in-android/)?

This way, by the time they filled everything out and are committed, going outside the app to press submit a second time will not deter them. The pop up would only need to contain 'rating amount' (stars) and 'text field' (optional), to pass to its analogue in the Play Store. It is possible to not just go to the Play Store page but also open that dialogue right?

Looking forward to your wisdom on this. :)

Comment: I am prett sure, you can't achieve this. If you find out, please share your knowledge :)

Comment: I suspect that store operators would specifically want to prevent this to keep apps from scamming their ratings.

Comment: The appstore still requires unique Google user profiles to submit ratings, no?