# Android studio app, google play store share/rate

Tags: android-studio, google-play, share, rate

I am implementing a "share" and "rate app" feature in my app. Both of these features I'm assuming require a link to my google play store app page so that the user can share the app and when wanting to rate the app gets directed to the page.

My question is, since I haven't finished the app and posted it how do I get the link to my app to implement into my code if the app isn't finished yet and I don't have an play store listing for it?

Comment: getpackagename() will give you packagename and market to point to to google play store. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270591/rate-google-play-application-directly-in-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link is made up from two parts. First is common and second part is the package name of your app.

`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=` + `your.package.name`

Note that on mobile you can also use other url protocol, like `market://details?id=` to directly open Google Play, but the `https` one would work too.

Comment: That should be it. I used the market://details?id= for the rate feature however I needed the link for sending it to other users when "sharing".