# How can I set the rating value in the Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, rating, ratingbar

I found some good information about making a link to the Google Play Store on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270591/rate-google-play-application-directly-in-app).

My question is how can I set the rating value that I get from the user on my app and set it on the Google Play Store directly. So the user doesn't have to do the rating on my app and then on the Google Play Store again. Is this possible?

Comment: you can't, you can only bring user to your app page and let him/her rate

Comment: imagine that this was possible, many apps would just abuse this by silently rating everything to 5

Comment: for sane alternative check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816757/rate-this-app-link-in-google-play-store-app-on-the-phone