# Send rate to Google Play Store from your application

Tags: android, google-play, rating, feedback

Is there a way to send "rating" from your application to Google Play store? How?
I made a pop-up dialog for my application where I get a comment and a rate from the user. How can I send that feedback to Google Play store?

I'd like to have an experience, where user does not have to leave my app for the rating.

Using [this library.](https://github.com/stepstone-tech/android-material-app-rating)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rate Google Play application directly in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270591/rate-google-play-application-directly-in-app)

Comment: @Pater , there is way if you redirect playstore for ratting > check below url

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816757/rate-this-app-link-in-google-play-store-app-on-the-phone

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible (as of now) to send the rating to the play store. You can have your own prompt, and then send an intent to the play store, where the user can rate your app.
Google is working on a solution, similar to the iOS implementation, to allow the user to rate your app without leaving.

Android Central posted an article about this new (and upcoming feature): https://www.androidcentral.com/check-out-play-stores-new-app-review-feature-pictures

Edit: Android has added the option to have an In-App Review Flow. See this documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/kotlin-java

Answer (score 0):

I think that what the OP is asking is if Android has a way to display a google play dialog to rate the app directly. Something like what iOS have:

[image]

I just did a quick research trying to figure out and I couldn't find anything. Let me know if you have found a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

now google add in-app-review for rate and comment in google play store.
you can use this link for extra details:
https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/kotlin-java