# Review stars for store appcelerator android / ios

Tags: android, ios, appcelerator, review, vote

I need a module to allow people to rate the app inside of it.
I've founded this link for ios :

https://github.com/hansemannn/titanium-review-dialog

looks good, can i find the same for android ?!
Or any suggestions to open alertDialog with rating.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible for Android to rate an app outside the store:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11270668/5193915

You can open the market link so the user can rank you app there