# How do I rate Google Play application directly in my app on Kotlin language?

Tags: kotlin

I need to make rate option in my app.
I want to just provide ability for users to rate my app on Google Play.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rate Google Play application directly in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270591/rate-google-play-application-directly-in-app)

Comment: Yes, but this solution is on Java, but I need solution on Kotlin

Comment: Copy/Paste the Java code to a Kotlin file, and Android Studio will be happy to convert the code instantly.

Comment: Yes, Android Studio is cool!)) Does "Intellij Idea" also be able to convert Java code to Kotlin code?

Comment: By the way, this method doesn`t always work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution (Kotlin):

```
    fun rateApp() {
        val uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=$packageName")
        val myAppLinkToMarket = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
        try {
            startActivity(myAppLinkToMarket)
        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Impossible to find an application for the market", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

P.S. This code does not work on the simulator, use a real device.